# How can i do this in my SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have a question about SQL statement.

This SQL statement works fine, but I also want to find restaurants that have 0 in their `Restarurant_ID`. How can I make this happen in this statement?

```
SELECT ct.*, t.*
FROM exp_channel_titles AS ct
LEFT JOIN transactions AS t ON (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id)
WHERE t.cardid > 0
ORDER BY t.created DESC
```

Comment: By having a `exp_channel_titles.entry_id` with id `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
ct.*, t.*
FROM
exp_channel_titles as ct
LEFT JOIN
transactions as t on (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id)
WHERE
t.cardid > 0 and t.restaurant_id=0
order by t.created DESC
```

Comment: When i am doing that, nothing comes out. Not even my restaurant_id > 0

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by

```
WHERE t.cardid > 0 OR t.restaurant_id=0
```

if cardid  not mandatory to grater than 0 , you can also use AND to make sure that `t.cardid` also greater than 0

Comment: When i am doing that, nothing comes out. Not even my restaurant_id > 0

Answer (score 1):

Add `AND restaurant_id = 0` to your where clause

Answer (score 1):

In PHP:

```
 <?php

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT
         ct.*, t.*
         FROM
         exp_channel_titles as ct
         LEFT JOIN
         transactions as t on (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id)
         WHERE
         t.cardid > 0 and t.restaurant_id=0
         order by t.created DESC");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          echo $row['field'];
        }


    ?>
```

Comment: When i am doing that, nothing comes out. Not even my restaurant_id > 0